# Parsing XML in Google Apps Script for BGG API

Tags: xml, google-apps-script

I'm currently trying to pull information on Boardgames from the BGG xml api. The flow is something like this:

User enters boardgame name as a search->

script polls the api for games matching that name and returns the results->

User picks the correct result->

script takes the boardgame ID from the picked result and polls the api again using the ID which gives all the needed info.

Here is the code I'm working on:

```
var Name = "Betrayal at the house on the hill"

  // Call BGG API with query to display options for selection
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://boardgamegeek.com/xmlapi/search?search="+Name)

  // Parse the XML reply
  var document = XmlService.parse(response);
  var root = document.getRootElement();
```

Here is the output I receive from the search:

```
<boardgames termsofuse="[https://boardgamegeek.com/xmlapi/termsofuse](https://boardgamegeek.com/xmlapi/termsofuse)">
        <boardgame objectid="238032">

        <name primary="true">Betrayal at Baldur\&#039;s Gate and House on the Hill Promo Cards</name>           
<yearpublished>2017</yearpublished>
</boardgame>

        <boardgame objectid="10547">

        <name primary="true">Betrayal at House on the Hill</name>           
<yearpublished>2004</yearpublished>
</boardgame>

        <boardgame objectid="198452">

        <name primary="true">Betrayal at House on the Hill: Widow\&#039;s Walk</name>           
<yearpublished>2016</yearpublished>
</boardgame>

</boardgames>\
```

I can handle everything else from there. The issue I'm having, is that the boardgame's ID is wrapped up in an xml tag `<boardgame objectid="xxxxxx">`, and I can't figure out how to get the script to access that information. I can see the ID when I look at the output in the logs, but I can't figure out how to pull the ID into a variable. I have basically no xml experience which I'm sure is why I can't figure out something that seems fairly simple. I'm using google apps script on a google sheet (basically javascript).

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26531907/parse-xml-using-google-apps-script) is a post I found that helped me get started, but he doesn't seem to need the ID for his use case. Sadly, I do.

Any thoughts or suggestions would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Zelyn on reddit was able to answer my question. The necessary code to pull the ID is below:

```
var document = XmlService.parse(bggXml);
var root = document.getRootElement();
var games = root.getChildren('boardgame');

for (var i = 0; i < games.length; i++) {
    var id = games[i].getAttribute('objectid').getValue();
    // do something with id
}
```